# Upload a file using selenium with find element

Tags: python, selenium, browser, automation

I'm trying to upload a file to the following website: kapwing.com/subtitles

I have:

```
driver=webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.kapwing.com/subtitles")

pageSource = driver.page_source
splitted = pageSource.split(" ")
variable = splitted[2119]
final_variable = variable.split('"')[1]
time.sleep(5)
print(final_variable)
driver.find_element_by_id(final_variable).send_keys("/Users/xx/Desktop/lol.mp4")
```

but it says ID cannot be found. I would appreciate any help.

Comment: Are you trying to type into the text box to the right of upload file where it asks for a url?

Comment: @Lzypenguin I'm just trying to upload from computer. but either can work..

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to click on the upload button and then type out the location to your file in the popup, you are not going to be able to locate the textbox in the popup till you click it.

you could use this:

```
import keyboard

upload_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="upload-button-input-887ef963-27c3-46cc-8de5-dec5fc340dd7"]')
upload_button.click()

time.sleep(5)

keyboard.write('/Users/xx/Desktop/lol.mp4')
keyboard.press_and_release('return')
```

Comment: It errors out by saying the ID doesn't exist. I believe it's because it's dynamic? "Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id="upload-button-input-887ef963-27c3-46cc-8de5-dec5fc340dd7"]"}"

Answer (score 0):

Try this one should work for you:

```
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='upload-button-input-41d31461-54e1-47a3-978b-82b3077fe73e']")
element.send_keys("/Users/xx/Desktop/lol.mp4")
```

Answer (score 0):

The webpage has `input[type='file']` input field that means you can directly do `.send_keys`

```
time.sleep(5)
driver.find_element_by_css_selector(input[type='file']).send_keys("/Users/xx/Desktop/lol.mp4")
```

**PS** `time.sleep(5)` is just for visibility purpose.  You can remove that as well.

Answer (score 0):

`sendKeys` function works for `input` tag. You need to find the element and send the location of `file`.

```
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[contains(@id,'upload-button-input')]")
element.send_keys("location of file.")
```